# What is the fastest way to test a website across all browsers and browser versions?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-automation-framework

I have made a social media web application and I want to test the compatibility of the web application for the different type of browsers and browser version.

I started testing my web application manually but it is not an efficient way to cover all combination of browsers and browser versions. So is there any way possible to do same?

Comment: What automated ways of testing your app you looked at? You are asking many questions, but likely you will get similar answers. Learn how to ask answerable questions first. Patience, grasshopper.

Comment: How many different types of browsers and versions have you decided is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *you should have things automated*. Then, when you have a battery of automated tests, you have several options to choose from:

- use services like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/start) or [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) that provide remote selenium server capabilities covering tons of different operating systems and browsers. They are not free, but solve the "selenium server as a service" problem for you.
- configure your own [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) with multiple selenium nodes for different operating systems and browsers

Comment: I would also add that "test an app across all the browsers and all the versions" is kinda false target. You will never please everyone so you have to chose which browsers to support and which not.

Comment: @AlexeyR. good point! We do have a special json file specifying which versions we support and what not. Then, we run automated tests on these browsers (and their versions) only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what browsers/versions are used by **your own** users. Testing browsers which are not used by your users (even if used on other websites) is waste of effort.

Comment: Be careful. Not testing a browser because your users don't use that browser can be a self-fulfilling prophecy. Maybe they don't use Firefox because your application doesn't work on Firefox, for example...